# How can I get WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions to accept an audience with an asterisk

Tags: c#, owin, katana, adal

My Azure Active Directory application URI contains an asterisk, something like `https://*.mywebapp.com"`.
AAD can successfully acquire a token for the `https://test.mywebapp.com` resource for this app.

On the service side I'm using OWIN and `WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions` to validate the token.
The problem is that specifying an audience with an asterisk is not supported.

With the following code, token validation returns false for a token with audience `https://test.mywebapp.com`

```
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Tenant = c_azureActiveDirectoryTenant,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidAudiences = new[] { "https://*.mywebapp.com" },
                        SaveSigninToken = true,
                    },                       
                });
```

Looking at the `AudienceValidator` and `IssuerValidator` code on GitHub, I can easily understand the reason - The code compares exact strings. I would expect the code to respect wildcards, is this by design or a just a bug? Any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take control of the AudienceValidation by setting TokenValidationParameters.AudienceValidator delegate. You can then do whatever you need to do.